# How to deal with a table, having more than 2000 column , to calculate avg of all the numeric columns in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I working on a table with number of columns>2000, I want to carry out the stats of all the numeric column of table, I created a dataframe as

df = sqlContext.sql("select * from table")

I tried using **describe()** on the dataframe as df.describe() but it's like process is running for lifelong... For around 5-6 hours but no response.

Could anyone please help me out with the workaround using pyspark. Thanks in advance.

P.S => In scala there is a function called sliding that can be used as 
**allColumns.sliding(200)** which will slide the 200 columns and further we can carry out the avg of that columns.

Also i need to collect all the parts i.e. P1 -> 1-200 Columns, P2 -> 201-400 etc. and join them to get the data collectively.

Answer (score 0):

You could directly compute your average in the sql request like:

```
# collect the column name and shape then in a list
colname = sqlContext.sql("describe table1").select("col_name").collect()
colname = [x.col_name for x in colname]
# build the query (average on each column)
df = sqlContext.sql("select " +",".join(["AVG({0}) AS avg_{0}".format(x) for x in colname]) + " from table")
# As a result you will get the average for each column (as Row)
df.collect()
```

Not sure to answer your question. Don't hesitate comment.